# How to properly model and test a method that is dependent from another?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, domain-driven-design

I'm developing an example of card game. And while developing that, i couldn't find a way to properly create a unit test for the method `DistributeCards()`.
And that's because, the `DistributeCards()` method is dependent of the `StartNewRound()` method to run. And inside the `StartNewRound()` method, there's a call to the `DistributeCards()` method.

GameManager Class:

```
public class GameManager
{

    private Game _Game { get; set; }

    public GameManager(Game game)
    {
        _Game = game;
    }

    public void AddPlayer(Player player)
    {
        _Game.PlacePlayer(player);
    }

    public void StartNewRound()
    {
        // Shuffle Cards
        _Game.ShuffleCards();
        // Update current playing player
        _Game.PlayingPlayer = _Game.GetPlayerAtChair(_Game.GetNextOccupiedChairIndex(0));

        DistributeCards();
    }

    public void DistributeCards()
    {
        //Make Card Distribution
    }
}
```

So my test was going to be like the following:

```
[TestFixture()]
public class GameManagerTests
{
    private GameManager _manager;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _manager = new GameManager(new Game(6));
    }

    [Test()]
    public void DistributeCardsTest()
    {
        _manager.AddPlayer(new Player("1", "test", 10));
        _manager.AddPlayer(new Player("2", "test", 10));
        _manager.AddPlayer(new Player("3", "test", 10));
        _manager.AddPlayer(new Player("4", "test", 10));

        _manager.StartNewRound();
        
    }
}
```

We can see in the `DistributeCardsTest()` test method that at the point that i call `StartNewRound()` the `DistributeCards()` method has already run. And if i would call it again, i would be running it twice, and in my head that a little bit strange.

So i don't know if i can model the method to be more testable somehow or if i should change something in the test itself like creating a mock or something like that.

Obs.: I'm trying to use DDD modeling.

Comment: From your code, it is not obvious that the **method has already run**

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but what do you mean ? The last line of the `StartNewRound()` is a call to the `DistributeCards()`.

Answer (score 1):

If distributing cards is part of starting a new game, you can make DistributeCards() private and test StartNewRound() as a whole (with Game methods being mocked).

If cards are to be distributed in scenarios other than game start, DistributeCards() becomes more like a service, meaning:

1. it should be tested as an independent unit.
2. it should be mocked when invoked as part of different scenarios (game start etc.)

Here's an example how to redesign GameManager:

```
public interface ICards
{
    void Distribute();
}

public class Cards : ICards
{
    public Cards(Game game)
    {
        this.Game = game;
    }

    private Game Game { get; }

    public void Distribute()
    {
        // Operate Game object...
    }
}

public class GameManager
{
    public GameManager(Game game, ICards cards)
    {
        this.Game = game;
        this.Cards = cards;
    }

    private Game Game { get; }

    private ICards Cards { get; }

    public void StartNewRound()
    {
        this.Game.ShuffleCards();
        this.Game.PlayingPlayer = this.Game.GetPlayerAtChair(this.Game.GetNextOccupiedChairIndex(0));

        this.Cards.Distribute(this.Game);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your opinion : )